# Unity: Could not allocate memory: System out of memory! Memorylabel Texture

Tags: unity-game-engine, apk

I know a lot of people get this issue but I have a hard time getting it fixed. Partly because this is my first Unity game.

So it is a 2d Android game using Unity 5.5.2f1 and I get the error when I try out my build. Note that this is my first build despite the game being 95% complete. I got stuck on building the APK for a while so I postponed fixing it. Building into an APK works fine but then when I run the game, after the intro screen the app crashes with the following debuglog (check note in the middle for where the crash occurs):

> 01-19 22:51:59.768: E/Unity(21604): Unable to find AudioPluginMsHRTF
>   01-19 22:51:59.769: E/Unity(21604): Unable to find
>   AudioPluginOculusSpatializer 01-19 22:51:59.848: D/Unity(21604):
>   GL_AMD_compressed_ATC_texture GL_AMD_performance_monitor
>   GL_AMD_program_binary_Z400 GL_EXT_debug_label GL_EXT_debug_marker
>   GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer GL_EXT_robustness
>   GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_EXT_texture_type_2_10_10_10_REV
>   GL_NV_fence GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture GL_OES_depth_texture
>   GL_OES_depth24 GL_OES_EGL_image GL_OES_EGL_sync
>   GL_OES_EGL_image_external GL_OES_element_index_uint
>   GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap GL_OES_fragment_precision_high
>   GL_OES_get_program_binary GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil
>   GL_OES_depth_texture_cube_map GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8
>   GL_OES_standard_derivatives GL_OES_texture_3D GL_OES_texture_float
>   GL_OES_texture_half_float GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear
>   GL_OES_texture_npot GL_OES_vertex_half_float
>   GL_OES_vertex_type_10_10_10_2 GL_OES_vertex_array_object
>   GL_QCOM_alpha_test GL_QCOM_binning_control GL_QCOM_driver_control
>   GL_QCOM_perfmon_global_mode GL_QCOM_extended_get GL_QCOM_extended_get2
>   GL_QCOM_tiled_rendering GL_QCOM_writeonly_rendering GL_EXT_sRGB
>   GL_EXT_sRGB_write_control GL_EXT 01-19 22:51:59.848: D/Unity(21604):
>   _texture_sRGB_decode GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic GL_EXT_multisampled_render_to_texture GL_EXT_color_buffer_float
>   GL_EXT_color_buffer_half_float GL_EXT_disjoint_timer_query 01-19
>   22:52:00.564: W/Unity(21604): OnLevelWasLoaded was found on
>   GameManager 01-19 22:52:00.564: W/Unity(21604): This message has been
>   deprecated and will be removed in a later version of Unity. 01-19
>   22:52:00.564: W/Unity(21604): Add a delegate to
>   SceneManager.sceneLoaded instead to get notifications after scene
>   loading has completed 01-19 22:52:00.564: W/Unity(21604):  01-19
>   22:52:00.564: W/Unity(21604): (Filename: Line: 382)

***when trying to transition from the scene 0 to scene 1***

> 01-19 22:52:31.082: E/Unity(21604): Could not allocate memory: System
>   out of memory! 01-19 22:52:31.082: E/Unity(21604): Trying to allocate:
>   327716B with 16 alignment. MemoryLabel: Texture 01-19 22:52:31.082:
>   E/Unity(21604): Allocation happend at: Line:464 in  01-19
>   22:52:31.082: E/Unity(21604): Memory overview 01-19 22:52:31.082:
>   E/Unity(21604): [ ALLOC_DEFAULT ] used: 10185997B | peak: 10217647B |
>   reserved: 10604339B  01-19 22:52:31.082: E/Unity(21604): [
>   ALLOC_TEMP_JOB ] used: 0B | peak: 0B | reserved: 524288B  01-19
>   22:52:31.082: E/Unity(21604): [ ALLOC_GAMEOBJECT ] used: 665219B |
>   peak: 665219B | reserved: 752068B  01-19 22:52:31.082: E/Unity(21604):
>   [ ALLOC_GFX ] used: 48855042B | peak: 50558706B | reserved: 48861160B 
>   01-19 22:52:31.082: E/Unity(21604): [ ALLOC_PROFILER ] used: 0B |
>   peak: 0B | reserved: 0B  01-19 22:52:31.082: E/Unity(21604): [
>   ALLOC_TEMP_THREAD ] used: 110072B | peak: 0B | reserved: 2719744B 
>   01-19 22:52:31.082: E/Unity(21604):  01-19 22:52:31.082:
>   E/Unity(21604): (Filename: Line: 996)

Now I have done the following:
-Made the intro screen as light as possible (at first I didn't even have one)
-Emptied the resource folder (cut my project size in half and increased build speed but that is about it)
-OpenGLES is set to 3 (someone advised this)

(note that there are no textures larger than 1000x1000)

As I said before, this is my first project in Unity. I am not the best programmer in the worl but over the last year I managed to put this little RPG together and I am quite ready to actually finish up and release! I would really appreciate any advise anyone can give!

Cheers,

Daan

Comment: Note: Changing the scene from 0 to 1 into 0 to 2 still triggers the same warning. I do have to add that both scene 1 and 2 are very similar.
I also added debug statements on every gameobject to give a print when they are awake but no prints show up. I did this in an effort to find the faulty gameobject (if there is one) but no show.

Btw, everything works great in the unity editor.

Answer (score 0):

Go to File > Build Settings and make sure Scripts Only Build is unchecked.

This has fixed it for me in Unity 2018.3.7f1.